Do Aurora Serverless v2 supports Foreign Data Wrapper (FDW)?
Currently I'm using Aurora Serverless v1 which don't supports FDW(foreign data wrappers). I need to setup FDW for some requirement. I just want some ways to tackle this situation.
1.First approach may be to move to "serverless aurora postgreSQL" to "aurora postgreSQL" which supports FDW.
2. Second approach would be to upgrade from "Aurora Serverless v1" to "Aurora Serverless v2" , but for that i need to know if "Aurora Serverless v2" supports FDW or not?
I'm expecting to discuss this approaches further and finalise best out of them( or get other suggestions as well)

have you found the answer for that?

@JoeyYiZhao not till now. Although more likely to move with first approach( "serverless aurora postgreSQL" to "aurora postgreSQL".

I think it is working now for serverless version2. I just tested it.
